# customize box search in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search

I use flatsome theme.
How can I modify the search box to get this form .. (tous=categories)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5hJf.png)

Comment: Enlighten us with what you've tried (code for example...) . No need to do things double. BTW.. finish the tour!

Comment: It is always good to start your question with a problem, then explain what you have tried already and conclude with what you expect to find. The more information you provide the easier it is to help you, like a link to the theme in question.